# MySQL query, if dates are subsequent

Tags: mysql

There is a piece of checking I don't want to loop through in PHP, but want to let MySQL solve. Not only because it's cleaner, but also because the PHP loop is noobish and (in this case) quite server demanding seeing it's a quite big table.

However, I have no idea where to start with this query (noobish, I know)

I have two tables:

1. shifts
2. orders

I would like to query the max amount of subsequent days a worker made an order. For instance:

Worker has worked on:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-02
2014-05-03
2014-05-04
2014-05-07
2014-05-10
2014-05-14
```

Orders came in on:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-02
2014-05-03
2014-05-04
2014-05-07
2014-05-10
2014-05-14
```

Then the result would be 7. Cause every day at least one order came in. And we want to match each day with an order. We don't care how many orders a day, we just want to know that he did have et least an order

Now a second example.

Worker has worked on:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-02
2014-05-03
2014-05-04
2014-05-07
2014-05-10
2014-05-14
```

Orders came in on:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-03
2014-05-04
2014-05-07
2014-05-10
2014-05-14
```

This should result in 5. Cause he missed an order on 2014-05-02 which breaks his order streak.

So the question is, is this even possible in MySQL or should I just continue with my original plan of noobish looping.

Note: database load is not really an issue.

Comment: I imagine that to solve this you'd have to left join onto the orders(so you can check for ones that don't match), group by the date(to remove duplicate orders). After that I'm unsure, possibly use a `group_concat(IF(OrderId IS NULL, 'f', 't') ORDER BY WorkingDate)` to do the aggregating and use a greedy regexp matching the string 't' to find the longest match?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT worker_id, MAX(counter) AS max_days
FROM (
    SELECT worker_id, 
           @counter := IF(o.date IS NULL, 0, 
                          IF(worker_id != @prev_worker, 1, 
                             @counter + 1)) AS counter,
           @prev_worker := worker_id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT s.worker_id, s.date, o.date
        FROM shifts AS s
        LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON s.worker_id = o.worker_id AND s.date = o.date
        ORDER BY s.worker_id, s.date) AS j
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0, @prev_worker := null) AS vars) AS w
GROUP BY worker_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` causes `o.date` to be `NULL` whenever there's no matching row in `orders` for the row in `shifts`.

Comment: There are some significant optimizations that can be got out of this by not using a loop here(which is what your counter is simulating in SQL), you've effectively turned what started off as a multi-threaded search into a linear scan over every single day/worker in the database.

Comment: He wants to count the number of consecutive rows that match a criteria. I'm not sure how to do this without a loop. MySQL doesn't have a `ROW_NUMBER()` function, so there's no other good way to test adjacencies.